# Select elements based on part of a background url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select all elements that have a background image that contains specific text. For example, the element could have this style:

```
background-image: url(http://images.myServer.com/4536);
```

I want to find all elements whose background image urls contain "myServer".

I've seen [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249881/jquery-select-element-based-on-background-image-name) that match the url exactly, like:

```
if ( $(this).css('background-image') === 'http://images.myServer.com/4536' )
```

but nothing that finds a partial match.

Comment: So [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Use indexof('myServer')!=-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a filter and `indexOf`

```
var collection = $(elements).filter(function() {
    return this.style.backgroundImage.indexOf( 'myServer' );
});
```